# when does $1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}-...$converge

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

when does $1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}...$ converge and diverge

where the pattern is the Thue morse sequence with adding and subtracting. $+--+-++--++-+--+...$.

I plotted it with 31 terms and found that it might diverge between 7 and 6.

I'm sure how to test it?

Comment: I have a new question on how to write it in elementary functions here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757026/can-you-write-1-x-fracx22-fracx33-with-elementary-functions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It absolutely converges, so the signs don't matter.  Compare with the series for $e^x$.

Comment: okay so here is another question how can I write it in elementary functions? @brianMoehring

Comment: @BriggyT That's a much more complicated question.  If you want to ask it in another question, someone else might be better equipped to answer it.