# Can you write $1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}-\dots$ with elementary functions

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, elementary-functions

Can you write

$$1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}-\dots$$

with elementary functions, where the function is related to the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3757009/9340)?
I was told it converges with all inputs.

But I don't know how to write it in elementary functions. Thanks

Comment: Thue - Morse sequence

Comment: This is the "exponential generating function of the Thue–Morse sequence". Searching on that phrase didn't turn up anything immediately helpful, unfortunately. If $I$ is the integral operator $I(f)(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$, then the series is the result of applying the integral operator $(1-I)(1-I^2)(1-I^4)(1-I^8)\cdots$ to the constant function $1$. Don't know if that helps either.

Comment: @GregMartin so for all (2^(2n))th derivatives of f(x). at the point, x=0 is always 1 and for all n. (2^(2n+1))th derivatives it's -1 for all n. I don't know if this helps?

Comment: Why do you think there should be an expression in term of elementary functions?

Comment: Note: if there was a closed form, one could derive a formula for the Dirichlet series associated with the Thue-Morse sequence at s=2 by adapting Euler's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(2)$. This is still an open problem.